# Logging inbound firewall pings, organization by IP

Tags: windows, firewall, ddos

Is there some way or a program that can do this? A VPS of mine has been receiving a very large number of pings, almost to mini-ddos level. I need to track the pings made, by IP address (or even just output to a simple log file)

Is there anything built into windows to do this?

If not, is there a pre-existing program that can?

If not, is it possible to build one using the .net framework?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What OS?  What are you using for the firewall?  Are you behind a firewall or router?

Comment: XP SP2, Windows Firewall, no idea. I'd say its more of a software question, this could apply to a home computer as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to log this, just get yourself a copy of [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/)/[tcpdump](http://www.winpcap.org/windump/) and capture all icmp traffic to a file.

Answer (score 0):

Many home computers live behind NAT, so pings rarely reach the machine itself.

What is the purpose of keeping track of the pings?  Chances are they have faked up source addresses, and are therefore not really useful in tracking down the source.  I'd recommend asking your VPS host to block ICMP PING (but only the PING!) to your machines for a while, or at least rate limiting it.

If it is a mini-DDoS, then chances are they will want to be involved in tracking it down, as it may be an attack on them, not you.  Or a neighbor in the rack.  Or on you, but they will still want to know.

They will have to find which of their pipes it comes in on and work upstream from there to get it stopped or mitigated.